# How To Close an Account

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is there a way That I can close my account? I just didn't find my place here and therefore I'd like to leave.

Comment: You can leave without closing your account if you want. No one is forcing you ever to log-in again.

Comment: @Double AA Thanks but I asked how to close it!

Comment: @Double AA metamen has recently posted a question which was closed as a duplicate of this. It was obviously not a duplicate but a תרעומת against aggressive behaviors. I feel that the matter was in reality censured.

Comment: @Isaac Moses see my comment above

Answer (score 6):

While I can't speak for everyone here, I'd certainly be sorry to see you go!

But, to answer your question....there is a link on the bottom of the page that says "[contact us](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/contact)." In the dropdown menu that says "what can we help you with?," select the option that says "I need to delete my account." Fill out the information there (if you're logged in, everything that you're required to fill out is filled out automatically), and your account should be deleted by Stack Exchange staff in a short amount of time (I think under a week, but I'm not 100% sure).

Keep in mind that 3 days is an incredibly short amount of time to get used to Mi Yodeya -- you might want to consider sticking it out for a little bit more to see if you can figure it out. In the end, of course, that decision is yours.

Comment: +1.  David, I hope you'll consider taking a short break (if you need some time away) and then coming back.  An unused account does no harm, and it'll be here when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about how to delete your account on in the Help Center [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Note no one is making you log in and read things you don't want to read. Feel free to just stop logging in. That way if you ever want to return you can do so and still be in control of your contributed content.

Comment: _MOD NOTE: This was written as an answer to another question and merged hither._